# set image preview in edit form from database

Tags: typescript, file-upload, formik, preview

I have an issue with displaying a photo preview on an edit form using Formik in Next.js-TypeScript. Here is the code:

```
 const [previewImg, setPreviewImg] = useState<any>()
  const [upload, setUpload] = useState(false)

const formik = useFormik({
    enableReinitialize: true,
    initialValues: {
      empId: props.id,
      file: emp.file, },
onSubmit: async (values) => {
      dispatch(EditEmpRequest(values));
      props.setRefresh(true);
      setShowModal(false);
      },   
  });

//config
const uploadConfig = (name: any) => (event: any) => {
    let reader = new FileReader()
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    console.log(event.target.files);
    reader.onload = () => {
        formik.setFieldValue('file', file)
        setPreviewImg(reader.result)
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    setUpload(true)
}

  const onClear = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setPreviewImg(null)
    setUpload(false)
}

//form photo
<label htmlFor="empPhoto">Photo</label>
<div className="mt-2 flex justify-center rounded-lg border border-dashed border-gray-900/25 px-6 py-10">
  {upload === false ? (
                    <span>Empty file</span>
                      ) : (
                    <>
                      <div>
                        {previewImg && <img src={previewImg} alt="img" className="max-w-xs" width={100} />}
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <button
                          className="text-red-700 hover:text-white text-xs border border-red-700 hover:bg-red-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-red-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center mr-2 mb-2 dark:border-red-500 dark:text-red-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-red-600 dark:focus:ring-red-900"
                          onClick={onClear}
                        >
                          Remove
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      </>
                    )}
                  </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input className="block w-full text-sm text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:text-gray-400 focus:outline-none dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400" aria-describedby="user_avatar_help" id="user_avatar" type="file" onChange={uploadConfig('file')} />
                        <div className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-300" id="user_avatar_help"> </div>
                    </div>
```

The code is almost the same as my ADD form code. So, there needs to be some adjustments to make the image preview from Formik in my EDIT, but I still haven't found a solution for this yet.
hope someone can help me. thanks..